# How to get rid of the array size error in this scenario while using Countifs()

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns and am trying to count the nonblank cells in column B based on a specific corresponding value in column A. So I am using `COUNTIFS($A$3:$A,"GA",len(trim($B7:$B)),">0")` to calculate that.

First criteria range is Column A and the criteria is if cell value equals "GA".

I want the second criteria range to be Column B and the criteria to be len(trim(cell)) > 0 but obviously I am not specifying it correctly and getting the following error, instead of the expected result of 7.

Please help in how I should achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Well, seems to me that the error states the problem.  One starts on row three while the other starts on row 7 thus making the arguments different sizes.

Comment: Hi Scott: Yes, that is a mistake that inadvertently crept in as I was  trying to cut down on the spreadsheet only for the relevant columns; but I think the problem may be something else. Even if I correct it I still get the same error - pls see in updated screen shot in OP. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo? Should be...

`=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A,"GA",len(trim($B3:$B)),">0")`

(You had `$B7:$B`.)

You can shorten this anyway:

`=COUNTIFS(A3:A,"GA",B3:B,"<>")`

Comment: Thanks Eric. The typo was inadvertent but was not the reason for the error. The syntax you suggested actually works. My question is why is it so - is it, I should not give a functional treatment to the criteria range in Countifs()? In other words if in some scenario, I actually need to apply some function on the range to compare against the specific criteria, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would try to `TRIM` a column of numbers, to start with, or why you needed to reference the `LEN` of numeric data (since both `TRIM` and `LEN` are string functions). That is part of the problem. A version of your original formula and condition could have worked: `=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A,"GA",$B3:$B,">0")` . Beyond that, I'm afraid I don't really understand your question here.

Comment: I used Len(Trim()) to catch anyone entering a space or ' in the cell of that column rather than a number. Trim will remove the space and Len will ensure I do not have an empty cell. That was my original thought process.